# Mysql Count number of Rows Depending on Date

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Well, I don't know what title it should be nor how can I explain it, but I'll do my best to explain my problem.

I have this table consists of certain data that focuses on **date_participated** and **fblike_point**.

[image]

Well, my desired output should be

***2013-03-20 1***

***2013-03-19 3***

So basically, **each date will count the number of fblike_point**.

On 2013-03-19 it has **total of 3 fblike_point** and on 2013-03-20 it has a **total of  1 fblike_point**

and **my problem** is, I'm outputting not my desired results, I'm getting a result of **2013-03-19 4**

It stays in 1 date and counts the number of fblike_point

Here is my code for that.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT date_participated, COUNT(fblike_point) as fblike FROM event_raffles WHERE ticket_id='". $ticket_id ."' AND event_table='". $event_table ."' AND status='1' ORDER BY date_participated DESC";
$result = db_query($query);

foreach ($result as $values) {
    echo $values->date_participated . " " . $values->fblike . "<br>";
}
```

Any solutions for this stuff? Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: use `mysql_num_rows()` function to count number of rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should alter your query to use a `GROUP BY` instead of the `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT date_participated, COUNT(fblike_point) as fblike 
FROM event_raffles
GROUP BY date_participated
```

The way you've used `DISTINCT` is to get all unique dates and for each result, add the amount of records returned in the *entire* resultset.

Using a `GROUP BY` allows you to use any aggregate function available *on that group*.

---

**Edit**

As been mentioned by @ysth, instead of using `COUNT` you might want to use `SUM` depending on the possible values that `fblike_point`can have.

Using `SUM` would actually be the more sensible course of action.

Comment: or possibly SUM(fblike_point), depending what other values than 1 it might have and what should result in those cases

Comment: @ysth - Your are right, thanks. I have edited the answer to add the *warning*.

Comment: err, if fblike_point is null or 1, both will return the same; if it is 0, that row won't be counted by sum but will be counted by count

Answer (score 1):

use below query by removing `DISTINCT` and replacing `ORDER BY` to `GROUP BY`

```
$query = "SELECT date_participated, COUNT(fblike_point) as fblike FROM event_raffles WHERE ticket_id='". $ticket_id ."' AND event_table='". $event_table ."' 
AND status='1' GROUP BY date_participated DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT date_participated, COUNT(fblike_point) as fblike FROM event_raffles WHERE ticket_id='". $ticket_id ."' AND event_table='". $event_table ."' AND status='1' ORDER BY date_participated DESC";
```

with

```
$query = "SELECT  date_participated, COUNT(fblike_point) as fblike FROM event_raffles WHERE ticket_id='". $ticket_id ."' AND event_table='". $event_table ."' AND status='1' GROUP BY date_participated ORDER BY date_participated DESC";
```

Comment: You need to use group by here